# Z-Score +Table Usage

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Given average cost of 200, and standard deviation of 50, what is the probability that the individual will pay at least 300? I got the Z-score as 2 but now I'm wondering is the probability 0.977 or am I missing something.

Comment: You're missing something.  Pay attention to what your table represents... be it area under the curve to the *left* of your z-score or to the *right*.  Pay attention to what your problem is asking for, whether *at least* or *at most*.  A probability of $0.977$ is very high and so would correspond to a large area under the curve.  Your hypothetical scenario you are asking for the probability of having at least as much or *more* than something that's already far *over* the average which is unlikely to happen.

Comment: That $0.977$ is the area to the left of $z=2$, so it’s the probability that the individual will pay **at most** $300$. You want the area to the **right** of $z=2$, which is ... ?

Comment: 1-0.977 gotcha ty

Comment: In R, $P(Z > 2) = 1 - P(Z\le 2),$ obtained with code `1-pnorm(2)` which returns 0.02275013.  Also code `1 - pnorm(300,200,50)` returns exactly same answer.

Answer (score 1):

Comment continued. For such problems, it's always a good idea to try making a sketch. Here is a sketch for the original problem in R:

```
curve(dnorm(x,200,50), 50, 350, ylab="PDF", main="NORM(200,50)")
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v=300, col="red")
 abline(v=c(150,250), col="green2", lty="dotted")
```

[image]

Of course, your freehand sketch will not be a precise
as you'd get from software, but you can get a good
enough graph to avoid gross errors. [It helps to know
that the inflection points, between convex in the center
and concave in the tails, occur at $\mu\pm\sigma;$ here
that's $200\pm 50$ or 150 & 250. Areas outside of inflection points are about 16% on either side.]